# Cypress Component testing with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress, e2e-testing, component-testing, cypress-component-testing

Does "Cypress Component Testing" support cucumber testing. I know it's possible to run "Cypress e2e" tests with cucumber but I haven't seen anyone try to do the same with "Cypress Component" tests. Has one here done so?

I've tried implementing and have gotten a series of errors and I'm wondering if it is supported.

Comment: It should be possible (but I haven't tried it). For instance, the major syntax difference between Component and e2e testing is `cy,mount()` vs `cy.visit()`. The major difference is that Component tests run in the same window object as the test runner, so maybe the Cucumber plugin does not like that.

Comment: What exactly errors?